# How can I show that $U= \{(2r, -s^2, t) : r, s,t \in \mathbb R\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

I think it's not, but I have to use the three properties of subspaces to disprove it. This was my attempt, although I'm not sure if it's correct.

Proof of $0\in U$
take $(2(0), -0^2, 0) = (0, 0, 0)$. Indeed, $0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Therfore, the $0$ vector is in $U$.

Proof of addition closure:

Take $x = (2r_1, -(s_1)^2, t_1)$ and $y = (2r_2, -(s_2)^2, t_2)$

Then $x+y = (2(r_1 + r_2), -(s_1^2 + s_2^2), t_1  + t_2)$. Indeed, it is closed under addition since $2(r_1 + r_2)$ is a multiple of $2,$ $-(s_1^2 + s_2^2)$ can be represented as number squared and is less than $0,$ and $t_1 + t_2$ is a real number

Proof of closed under multiplication:$x = (2r_1, -(s_1)^2, t_1)$

$ax = (2ar_{1}, -a(s_1)^2, at_1)$ This test fails since if a is negative, $-a(s_1)^2>0$. Therefore, it is not a subspace.

Is this correct? I'm mainly worried about my proof of it being closed under addition. More importantly, is there a better way to disprove a set is not a subset without having to look for an example.

Comment: This seems correct. A counterexample shouldn't be too hard to find in this case, though. Obviously $(2,-1,0)\in U$ by letting $r=1,s=1,t=0$. Then $-1*(2,-1,0)=(-2,1,0) \notin U$ since this implies $s=\sqrt{-1} \notin \Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just turn my comment into an answer and address a couple more things. Firstly, the counterexample. It's obvious that $(2,-1,0)\in U$ by letting $r=1,s=1,t=0$. Then $-1*(2,-1,0)=(-2,1,0) \notin U$ since this implies that $-s^2=1$, or $s=\pm\sqrt{-1}\notin \Bbb{R}$. So that shows that $U$ is definitely not a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Generally, showing that a set is not subspace of some vector space is easiest by way of counterexample.

Comment: There is no problem with the proof that it is closed under addition.  This subset is in fact closed under addition (i.e. it is a semigroup).  The problem is only with multiplication.

Comment: @RobertIsrael You're right, I was making an improper conclusion; I'll edit that part out.